# how to get recently added product from all category in slider in magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I need recently added product on slider from all category....

Also I need current product category url for the product view...

I need Latest product image,name,price,and category url for product listing...

basically in slider div

```
<div>
     <div>
          <span>product image</span>
          <span>name</span>
          <span>price</span>
          <span>category url</span>

    </div>


</div>

for this i used this...

$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4))                   
                    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');

?>

<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 497px; overflow: hidden;">
         <?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product) : ?>

            <div>


             <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" 
                    >
                    <img u="image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image') ?>" width="250" height="497" 
                    alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>


           </div>

       <?php endforeach; ?>


        </div>

bt in  how can i get category id of each product...

I need to link category id on product image....
```

Answer (score 0):

Get New Products Collection by calling

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" column_count="6" products_count="0" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

In this call, the products will be displayed using `list.phtml`.

Here change this `list.phtml` to other file which displays a product slider (say `bx slider` or any other product slider).